# 3D Plotting in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I'm trying to create a 3D plot of a function, but the message 
"Error in persp.default(x = xseq, y = yseq, matrixz, phi = -5, theta = 50,  : incorrect z limits" 
appears. I have no idea why

```
yseq <- seq(1e-9,1e-7,by=1e-9)
xseq <- seq(1e-8,1e-4,by=1e-6)
matrixz <- matrix(data = 0,nrow=length(xseq),ncol=length(yseq))

persp(x=xseq,y=yseq, matrixz, phi=-5, theta=50, expand=0.5, col="red4",xlab="[Ca] cytosol",ylab="[InsP3]",zlab="J2(x,y)", ticktype="detailed")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: range(matrixz) is c(0, 0). Give it some data not just zeros

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `matrixz` is only filled with 0s and the `range` of it, does not please `persp` and explains your error message:

```
> range(matrixz)
[1] 0 0
```

You can fix this by defining a `zlim`:

```
yseq <- seq(1e-9, 1e-7, by=1e-9)
xseq <- seq(1e-8, 1e-4, by=1e-6)
matrixz <- matrix(data =0, nrow=length(xseq), ncol=length(yseq))

persp(xseq, yseq, matrixz, phi=-5, zlim=c(-1e-3, 1e-3), 
      theta=50, expand=0.5, col="red4",xlab="[Ca] cytosol",ylab="[InsP3]",zlab="J2(x,y)", 
      ticktype="detailed")
```

or by filling your matrix, with your data. Here we sample numbers from the uniform distribution:

```
matrixz <- matrix(data = runif(length(xseq)*length(yseq)), nrow=length(xseq), ncol=length(yseq))

persp(xseq, yseq, matrixz, phi=-5, theta=50, expand=0.5,    
      col="red4",xlab="[Ca] cytosol",ylab="[InsP3]",zlab="J2(x,y)",  
      ticktype="detailed")
```

If you don't want to bother with a particular `theta`, `phi`, etc. you can explore your 3D plot with `persp3d` from `rgl`:

```
library(rgl)
persp3d(xseq, yseq, matrixz)
```